# How to select all checkboxes with class "xxx"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Welcome,

It it possible to select all checkboxes / uncheck all checkboxes what have class "xxx" ?

I can't  use "name" and "ID" because there are generated dynamical via PHP and i don't know their name.

So maybye i can add class "xxx" for these what i wan't control ?

Is is possible ?

Or, if not possible.
Maybye i can select all / unselect  what are inside table with id "selectall" ?

Regards

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can do with jquery's **[`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method:

```
$('input.xxx').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

This finds all input elements with class `xxx` and checks them all. To un-check, them, you could do like:

```
$('input.xxx').attr('checked', false);
```

For checkboxes inside a table with id `selectall`, you can go about like:

```
$('table#selectall :checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

and to un-check them, you should do:

```
$('table#selectall :checkbox').attr('checked', false);
```

Or:

```
$('table#selectall :checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Thank You :)
It was really helpfully :)

You solve my problem ;)

Comment: I have only one more question.
Is it possible to use variable against xxx ?

var xxx;
xxx='something';

And how use it here

$('input.xxx')

Comment: @marc - Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), `var class = '.xxx'; $('input').filter(class).attr(...`

Comment: @marc: Yes, you can use a variable there too, and you can put it in like `$('input.' + varname) `

Comment: Thank you.

Full, working code is

function select_all($where)
{
$where='.'+$where;
$('input').filter($where).attr('checked', 'checked');
}

Answer (score 2):

To select all checkboxes with class "xxx":

```
$('.xxx:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

You can use `.removeAttr('checked')` to unselect them.

To select all checkboxes inside an element with id "selectall":

```
$('#selectall :checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: @Nick: Good point. I already removed it before I saw your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a "select all" you can do something like this:

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
  $(".xxx:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[You can test a simple demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gxPvw/), when you check it, all of the `.xxx` checkboxes get checked, and unchecked when you unchecked it, this is usually what you want in a "Check/Uncheck All" box at the top.